# Configuring gawk in order to use my malloc

Tags: c, gawk

I want to test gawk with my own malloc as part of a [project](http://cs.lth.se/english/courseeda050/edaf01-os-project/). I need some help with following step:

> Download gawk and type configure and make check.

I downloaded gawk from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/ . I chose:

> gawk-4.1.1.tar.gz              08-Apr-2014 14:58  4.1M

I have extracted the file and now when i type `configure` nothing happens, it can't recognize the command.

`make check` doesn't work either.

Have I downloaded something else?

Comment: Whats the output of `configure`?

Comment: Try running `./configure` instead of a plain `configure` in gawk's directory (where a file named `configure` should exist).